# Can David Poll's CollectionPrinter handle grouping in a datagrid?

Tags: silverlight, printing, reporting

I've been working with [David Poll's CollectionPrinter Control](http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/04/16/making-printing-easier-in-silverlight-4) and have successfully printed reports which use a DataGrid to display the collection. Without using grouping in the datagrid it paginates the document normally. However, as soon as I activate grouping following his instructions in one of the first comments from the link above, the grid attempts to display all the items in the first page and gets cut off (no more pagination).

Here is the code that I'm attempting to use for the grouped DataGrid:

```
<Printing:CollectionPrinter.BodyTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Height="Auto">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <CollectionViewSource x:Key="groupedCollection" Source="{Binding CurrentItems}">
                    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="BaFolioNum" />
                        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="CategoryDesc"/>
                    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                </CollectionViewSource>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <sdk:DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedCollection}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Resources>

                </sdk:DataGrid.Resources>
                <sdk:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
                    <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
                        <Setter Property="PropertyNameVisibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter Property="SublevelIndent" Value="10" />
                    </Style>
                </sdk:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>

                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SkU}"  Header="SKU" MinWidth="150" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemDesc}" Header="Product Description" Width="*"/>
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CorrectionsDisplay}" Header="Corrections?" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding QtyLocDisplay}" Header="Qty/Loc"/>
                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Printing:CollectionPrinter.BodyTemplate>
```

If anyone has had any luck grouping data and printing it using his method, I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comment I posted in his website at http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/04/16/making-printing-easier-in-silverlight-4#comment-7197 for an explanation of what I did to get it working.
I'll put up the code I changed as soon as I have some time.

Edit: As promised, here are the changes that I made for grouping to work.

First I added two interfaces to the Printing.Controls project

```
public interface IContainsCollectionViewSource
{
    CollectionViewSource PageCollectionSource { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public interface IContainsContext
{
    IContainsCollectionViewSource CollectionContext { get; }
}
```

In CollectionPrintContext.cs I added the following property to house the CollectionViewSource

```
private CollectionViewSource displayCollectionViewSource;
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the data grid collection view which can be used to group and sort the display control.
/// </summary>
public CollectionViewSource DisplayCollectionViewSource
{
    get
    {
        return this.displayCollectionViewSource;
    }
    set
    {
        if (!object.Equals(this.displayCollectionViewSource, value))
        {
            this.displayCollectionViewSource = value;
            PropertyChanged.Raise(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayCollectionViewSource"));
        }
    }
}
```

In CollectionPrinter.cs I then modified CalculateChild. New code has comments marking it

```
private void CalculateChild<T>(object signal)
    {
        Debug.Assert(!this._IsRoot);
        Popup popup = new Popup();
        Grid layoutContainer;
        popup.Child = layoutContainer = new Grid();
        layoutContainer.Children.Add(this);
        popup.Opacity = 0;
        layoutContainer.Opacity = 0;
        layoutContainer.IsHitTestVisible = false;
        popup.IsHitTestVisible = false;
        this.Width = popup.Width = this.CurrentPrintContext.PrintableArea.Width;
        this.Height = popup.Height = this.CurrentPrintContext.PrintableArea.Height;
        var items = (this.ItemsSource ?? new T[0]).Cast<T>().Skip(this.CurrentPrintContext.FirstItemIndex).ToArray();
        ObservableCollection<T> pageItems = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        this.CurrentPrintContext.CurrentItems = pageItems;
        //New Code Block Starts Here
        if (this.CurrentPrintContext.Host as IContainsContext != null)
        {
            if (((IContainsContext)this.CurrentPrintContext.Host).CollectionContext != null)
            {
                this.CurrentPrintContext.DisplayCollectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
                foreach (GroupDescription groupDescription in ((IContainsContext)this.CurrentPrintContext.Host).CollectionContext.PageCollectionSource.GroupDescriptions)
                {
                    this.CurrentPrintContext.DisplayCollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
                }
                foreach (SortDescription  sortDescription in ((IContainsContext)this.CurrentPrintContext.Host).CollectionContext.PageCollectionSource.SortDescriptions)
                {
                    this.CurrentPrintContext.DisplayCollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions.Add(sortDescription);
                }

                this.CurrentPrintContext.DisplayCollectionViewSource.Source = pageItems;
            }
        }
        //New Code Block Ends Here
        this.Dispatcher.DelayUntil(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    this.CurrentPrintContext.IsLastPage = false;
                    bool reachedEnd = false;
                    int itemsAdded = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        if (itemsAdded >= items.Length ||
                            (this.MaximumItemsPerPage != -1 && itemsAdded >= this.MaximumItemsPerPage))
                        {
                            reachedEnd = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        pageItems.Add(items[itemsAdded++]);
                        this.CurrentPrintContext.LastItemIndex = this.CurrentPrintContext.FirstItemIndex +
                                                                 itemsAdded - 1;
                        if (itemsAdded == items.Length)
                            this.CurrentPrintContext.IsLastPage = true;
                        this.CurrentPrintContext.NotifyPropertiesChanged();
                        //New Code Block Starts Here
                        if (this.CurrentPrintContext.DisplayCollectionViewSource != null) this.CurrentPrintContext.DisplayCollectionViewSource.View.Refresh();
                        //New Code Block Ends Here
                        //popup.UpdateLayout();
                        this._VisualChild.Measure(this.CurrentPrintContext.PrintableArea);
                    } while (this.CheckWidth() && this.CheckHeight());
                    while (!reachedEnd && itemsAdded != 1 &&
                           !(this.CheckExpandedWidth() && this.CheckExpandedHeight() &&
                             this.CheckExpandedWidthHeight()))
                    {
                        pageItems.RemoveAt(pageItems.Count - 1);
                        itemsAdded--;
                        this.CurrentPrintContext.LastItemIndex = this.CurrentPrintContext.FirstItemIndex +
                                                                 itemsAdded - 1;
                        this.CurrentPrintContext.IsLastPage = false;
                        this.CurrentPrintContext.NotifyPropertiesChanged();
                    }
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                        {
                            DriveAnimationsToCompletion(popup);
                            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                                {
                                    popup.IsOpen = false;
                                    popup.Child = null;
                                    layoutContainer.Children.Clear();
                                    lock (signal)
                                        Monitor.Pulse(signal);
                                });
                        });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }
            },
                                   () => this._VisualChild != null);
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

In my Printer's cs file I set the sorting and grouping. One thing to note is the way I have it setup, this PageCollectionViewSource serves only as a template for the grouping and sorting. No data will be stored in it.

```
public partial class InventoryPrinter : CollectionPrinter, IContainsContext
{
    private InvReportData context;
    public InvReportData Context
    {
        get
        {
            return context;
        }
        set
        {
            context = value;
            try
            {


                context.PageCollectionSource = new CollectionViewSource() ;
                //context.PageCollectionSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SkuP1nBr", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                //context.PageCollectionSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SkuP2tXt", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                //context.PageCollectionSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SkuP3nBr", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                //context.PageCollectionSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SkuP4tXt", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                //context.PageCollectionSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SkuP5", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                //context.PageCollectionSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("BaFolioNum", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                //context.PageCollectionSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("BaFolioNum"));
                context.PageCollectionSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("BaFolioDisplay"));
                context.PageCollectionSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("CategoryDesc"));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    public IContainsCollectionViewSource CollectionContext
    {
        get
        {
            return context;
        }
    }

    public InventoryPrinter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }
}
```

That InvReportData class I use to fill in information in the header and footer as well and it looks like this

```
public class InvReportData : IContainsCollectionViewSource
{
    public string BoatName { get; set; }
    public string ReportTypeLabel { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }

    public CollectionViewSource PageCollectionSource { get; set; }
}
```

And my xaml code for the templates binds to the DisplayCollectionViewSource.View instead of the CurrentItems property

```
    <Printing:CollectionPrinter.FooterTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Host.Context.Date}" />
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentPage, StringFormat='{}Page {0} '}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PageCount, StringFormat='{}/ {0}'}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Printing:CollectionPrinter.FooterTemplate>
<Printing:CollectionPrinter.BodyTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="ReportDataGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayCollectionViewSource.View}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <sdk:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
                <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
                    <Setter Property="PropertyNameVisibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Property="ItemCountVisibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Setter Property="SublevelIndent" Value="10" />
                </Style>
            </sdk:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>

            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SkU}"  Header="SKU" MinWidth="150" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemDesc}" Header="Product Description" Width="*"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CorrectionsDisplay}" Header="Corrections?" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding QtyLocDisplay}" Header="Qty/Loc"/>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Printing:CollectionPrinter.BodyTemplate>
```

And the final piece of code you will need to put in the window/control where the printer will be displayed/printed from. Here you setup the CollectionViewSource with the data and set it to the printer's ItemsSource

```
InvReportData headerFooterData = new InvReportData();
headerFooterData.BoatName = boatName;
headerFooterData.Date = DateTime.Today.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");
CollectionSource = new CollectionViewSource { Source = reportData }.View;
        CollectionSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("BaFolioNum", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        CollectionSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SkuP1nBr", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        CollectionSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SkuP2tXt", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        CollectionSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SkuP3nBr", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        CollectionSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SkuP4tXt", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        CollectionSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SkuP5", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        //CollectionSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("BaFolioNum"));
        CollectionSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("BaFolioDisplay"));
        CollectionSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("CategoryDesc"));

        printer.ItemsSource = CollectionSource;
        printer.Context = headerFooterData;
```

And those should be all the changes you have to make to get the grouping to work with datagrids. Enjoy.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out, but please post your solution rather than linking to it.